# Riemannian volume forms on a family of surfaces evolving by IMCF

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

Fix a closed hypersurface $\Sigma$ in a Riemannian $3$-manifold $(M,g)$. Let $\Sigma_t$ be a family of closed hypersurfaces evolving from $\Sigma$ by inverse mean curvature flow (IMCF) in $M$. That is, given $x\in\Sigma$, they obey
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_t(x)=-\frac{\mathbf{H}}{H^2}=\frac{1}{H}\nu,\tag{D}$$
where $\mathbf{H}$ is the mean curvature vector of $\Sigma_t$ and $\Phi_{t\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}:M\to M$ is a one-parameter family of diffeomorphisms such that $\Phi_0$ is the identity map and $\Phi_t(\Sigma)=\Sigma_t$. If $d\mu_{\Sigma_t}$ denotes the Riemannian volume form on $\Sigma_t$, I would like to show that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}d\mu_{\Sigma_t}=d\mu_{\Sigma_t}.\tag{1}$$
This formula is included in *Geometric Relativity* by Dan A. Lee, and he says that it can be inferred from Proposition 2.10, which reads:

> [image]

The $X$ here is a vector field on $M$ defined by
$$X(p)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\Phi_t(p),$$
and that $\hat{X}$ is the tangential part of $X$ obtained from the decomposition relative to the unit normal vector field $\nu$.

Idea: Since we are talking about the hypersurface case with $X$ being purely normal, I would opt for (P2) with vanishing $\hat{X}$, which gives me
$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\mu(\Sigma_t)=\int_\Sigma H\varphi d\mu_\Sigma=\int_\Sigma d\mu_\Sigma=(\text{the area of $\Sigma$}).\tag{2}$$
This is still far from the desired equation (1). As a matter of fact, I don't even know how the author ditched that particular time instant $t=0$. Could somebody tell me what else he might have done to translate (2) into (1)? Thank you.

**Added:** Maybe I missed something important. The author said Proposition 2.10 tells us that for any $t$,
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\Phi_t^*d\mu_{\Sigma_t})=\Phi_t^*(\mathrm{div}_{\Sigma_t}X_t)(\Phi_t^*d\mu_{\Sigma_t}),$$
where $X_t$ is defined by
$$X_t(\Phi_t(p))=\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_t(p),$$
but I don't see how this works.

Comment: Where in your argument do you use the fact that the flow is the IMCF?

Comment: @Deane Hello, I chose $\varphi=H^{-1}$ because $X=H^{-1}\nu$ according to the IMCF definition (D).

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in formula (1). As written it says the time derivative of the volume form is equal to the volume form which looks off to me.

Comment: @quarague Hi, this is all that it is in the book, although the author refers to the volume form as the area measure.

Comment: You need the following fact: if $d\alpha$ and $d\beta$ are measures such that for any compactly supported smooth function $\chi$, $$\int \chi\,d\alpha = \int \chi\,d\beta,$$ then $d\alpha = d\beta$.

Comment: You have to make a different choice for $\phi$ based on my previous comment.

Comment: @Deane Thank you, but I don't really get it. Since our $X$ here is fixed as $X=H^{-1}\nu$, how do I choose a different $\varphi$? Are you suggesting scaling $\nu$ to have a different $\varphi$?

Comment: (P1) holds for **any** vector field $X$. So you’re allowed to use it as many times as you want with different choices for $X$.

Comment: @Deane Thank you, but (P1) is obtained with the choice that $X(p)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\Phi_t(p)$. I'm afraid this formula doesn't apply to an arbitrary vector field.

Comment: @Wombat: (P1) is valid for any family $\Sigma_t$ or flow $\Phi_t,$ not just IMCF. Since you can extend any $X$ to a neighbourhood and then integrate it to get a corresponding flow, this formula indeed makes sense for arbitrary $X.$

Comment: $\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$Here's another observation. It or something similar to it plays a role.  $\Phi_t$ is obtained from $X_t$ by solving an ODE. This implies the following: Consider two time-dependent vector fields $X_t$ and $Y_t$ that are equal for $[0,T)\times O \subset \R\times M$, where $O$ is open. Let $\Phi_t$ and $\Psi_t$ be the respective flows such that $\Phi_0=\Psi_0$. Then there exists $[0,T')\times O' \subset [0,T)\times O$ on which $\Phi = \Psi$.

Comment: Also, couldn't you compute $d\mu_{\Sigma_t}$ by a direct calculation and then differentiate it with respect to time? It might be messy but should be straightforward. It never hurts to figure out your own proof. You'll eventually understand Lee's proof, but there's no urgency to do so.

Comment: @Deane Thank you for your great help. Please allow me some time to think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following formula is well known and probably found in most expositions of minimal (hyper)surfaces: Let $M$ be a manifold with Riemannian metric $g_M$ and $\Sigma$ be an $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold. Let $\Phi_t: \Sigma \rightarrow M$ be a smooth family of embeddings and $g_t = \Phi_t^*g_M$ be the family of induced Riemannian metrics such that at $t=0$,
$$ \partial_t\Phi = \phi \nu, $$
where $\phi$ is a smooth function on $\Sigma$ and $\nu$ is the unit normal to $\Sigma_0$ in the direction of $\partial_t\Phi$. Then the volume measure $d\mu_t$ of $g_t$ satisfies
$$ \partial_td\mu_t = \phi H d\mu_t. $$

Here is a calculation using local coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^{n-1})$ on $\Sigma$ that shows this: For $t \ge 0$, let
\begin{align*}
  g_{ij} &= g_M(\partial_i\Phi_t,\partial_j\Phi_t).
\end{align*}
It follows that
\begin{align*}
  \partial_tg_{ij} &= g_M(\nabla_t\partial_i\Phi,\partial_j\Phi)
                     + g_M(\partial_i\Phi,\nabla_t\partial_j\Phi)\\
         &= g_M(\nabla_i\partial_t\Phi,\partial_j\Phi)
           + g_M(\partial_i\Phi,\nabla_j\partial_t\Phi)\\
         &= g_M(\nabla_i(\phi\nu),\partial_j\Phi)
           + g_M(\partial_i\Phi,\nabla_j(\phi\nu))\\
         &= \phi(g_M(\nabla_i\nu,\partial_j\Phi)+g_M(\partial_i\Phi,\nabla_j\nu))\\
         &= 2\phi A_{ij},
\end{align*}
where $A_{ij}\,dx^i\,dx^j$ is the second fundamental form.
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
  \partial_td\mu_t &= \partial_t(\sqrt{\det g})\,dx.
\end{align*}
The formula now follows from the standard formula for the derivative of the determinant (when it is positive):
\begin{align*}
\partial_t(\log\det M)&= \operatorname{trace} M^{-1}\partial_tM.
\end{align*}

A key trick here is to pull everything back to the fixed manifold $\Sigma$ and view everything as time-dependent functions on $\Sigma$. Viewing them as functions on $\Sigma_t$ is more confusing for me, so I avoid it.

You'll have to verify carefully that each step is valid. If you haven't done calculations like this in the past, you might want to use local coordinates on $M$ as well. There are slicker ways to justify the calculation above, but I always recommend working it out in local coordinates first.

Comment: Sir, you are right about it. I'm not familiar with computations in local coordinates. And now I'm thinking about why we can't choose local coordinates $\{x^1,x^2\}$ on $(\Sigma_{\color{red}t},g_t)$ and compute $(g_t)_{ij}=g_t(\partial_i,\partial_j)$, since $$d_{\mu_{\Sigma_\color{red}{\ t}}}=\sqrt{\det(g_t)_{ij}}\ dx^1\wedge dx^2$$ is to be differentiated.

Comment: If you are able to do rigorous calculations using coordinates on $\Sigma_t$ rather than $\Sigma$, then that's fine. But notice that the domain of the coordinates $(x^1,x^2)$ changes with respect to $t$. For me, that's a lot harder to deal with than doing the calculation using coordinates on a fixed manifold $\Sigma$ that do not depend on t. If you look at my calculation, then only thing that depends on $t$ is $\Phi_t$. This simplifies the calculation quite significantly.

Comment: I feel like there was always a subtlety in this computation I never really understood. In the second equality of the computation of $\partial_t g_{ij}$, why does the Lie bracket $L:=[\partial_t\Phi,\partial_i\Phi]$ vanish? I assume that it that $L=\Phi_*[\partial_t,\partial_i]$, where we think of $\{\partial_t,\partial_i\}$ as coordinate vector fields on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times \Sigma$. But pushforwards of Lie brackets are tricky, so I was never sure on this point.

Comment: I'm with Deane here: abstract coordinates on $\Sigma_t$ could be completely unrelated to coordinates on $\Sigma$, and this doesn't help us do any computations. The idea is to use the chosen variation to transfer a fixed coordinate system on $\Sigma$ to the nearby $\Sigma_t$'s, [cf. the bottom of page 3 here](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/var_volume.pdf). The business about the naturality of the Lie bracket can also be found on Proposition 8.30 of the 2nd edition of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

Comment: @IvoTerek Hello, I read your lecture note: given a chart $(U;x^1,x^2)$ on $\Sigma$, we can produce a chart $(\Phi_t(U);x^1\circ\Phi_t^{-1},x^2\circ\Phi_t^{-1})$ on $\Sigma_t$, whose coordinates still depend on $t$. It doesn't seem to make any difference. Eventually, we still have to differentiate the entire RHS of $$d\mu_{\Sigma_{\ t}}=\sqrt{\det(g_t)_{ij}}\ dx_t^1\wedge dx_t^2.$$ I mean, how do I make $dx_t^1\wedge dx_t^2$ irrelevant to $t$ and thus mean me no harm when I take the $t$-derivative?

Comment: Looking quickly, I'm under the impression that you might be still omitting a pull-back: when we write $(\Phi_t^*){\rm d}\mu_{\Sigma_t} = v(t) {\rm d}\mu_\Sigma$ and take the $t$-derivative, we are looking at the right side instead of the left, and $t$ does not enter ${\rm d}\mu_\Sigma$ whatsoever.

Comment: @IvoTerek Please let me write down my computations and see what else I missed:
$$\begin{align}
d\mu_{\Sigma_{\ t}}&=\sqrt{\det(g_t)_{ij}}\ dx_t^1\wedge dx_t^2\\
&=\sqrt{\det(g_t)_{ij}}\ d(x^1\circ\Phi_t^{-1})\wedge d(x^2\circ\Phi_t^{-1})\\
&=\sqrt{\det(g_t)_{ij}}\ (\Phi_t^{-1})^*(dx^1\wedge dx^2)
\end{align}$$
What should I do to differentiate $(\Phi_t^{-1})^*$ with respect to $t$, please? Thank you.

Comment: Right. You won't really take the $t$-derivative of ${\rm d}\mu_{\Sigma_t}$, but instead of $\Phi_t^*{\rm d}\mu_{\Sigma_t}$, which, by your computation above, equals $\sqrt{\det(g_t)_{ij} \circ \Phi_t}\, {\rm d}x^1\wedge {\rm d}x^2$.

Comment: @IvoTerek I wish I could understand what you really mean, but I just can't get it: is it totally wrong to say $$d\mu_{\Sigma_{\ t}}=\sqrt{\det(g_t)_{ij}}\ d(x^1\circ\Phi_t^{-1})\wedge d(x^2\circ\Phi_t^{-1})?$$ And why should we take care of $\Phi_t^*{\rm d}\mu_{\Sigma_t}$? After all, the very truth we want to justify is whether $d\mu_{\Sigma_t}$ is preserved by $\partial_t$, isn't it?

Comment: The problem is that differentiating $ d\mu_{\Sigma_t} $ with respect to $t$ is that for different values of $t$, this is a volume form on different domains. In other words, if $t \ne t'$, then $d\mu_t$ is a differential form on $\Sigma_t$ and $d\mu_{t'}$ is a differential form on $\Sigma_{t'}$. It is not obvious how to differentiate this as $\Sigma_t$ moves in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I think it can be worked out. I think that in fact that might be what Lee is doing

Comment: @Deane May I ask a question, please? How do I interpret $\partial_i\Phi_t$? It doesn't look like a vector field. My guess would be that $$(g_t)_{ij}=g_t(\partial_i,\partial_j)=g_M((\Phi_t)_*\partial_i,(\Phi_t)_*\partial_j),$$ where $(\Phi_t)_*$ is the push-forward(differential) of $\Phi_t$. Thank you.

Comment: @Wombat, yes. That is correct.

Comment: @Deane Can I ask you a $\textbf{logical}$ question, please? I just derived $\partial_t(g_t)_{ij}=2\phi A_{ij}$ and $\partial_t(g_t)^{ij}=-2\phi A^{ij}$, using $\textbf{normal coordinates}$. Can I logically conclude from my result that any other local coordinates give $\partial_t(g_t)^{ij}=-2\phi A^{ij}$? I suppose not, because normal coordinates are not arbitrary coordinates.

Comment: @Wombat, that's not question about logic. That's a fundamental question about what a tensor is and how it behaves under change of coordinates..

Comment: @Deane I'm sorry. I found that  $\partial_t(g_t)^{ij}=-2\phi A^{ij}$ does hold for any local coordinates, because all we need is to differentiate $(g_t)^{ik}(g_t)_{k\ell}=\delta_\ell^i$ and trace the result with $(g_t)^{\ell j}$, which process does not rely on properties of normal coordinates at all.

Comment: @Deane Sir, if I expand on your calculation of $g(\partial_i(\phi\nu),\partial_j\Phi_t)$, is it like $$g(\partial_i(\phi\nu),\partial_j\Phi_t)=g\left(\ (\partial_i\phi)\nu+\phi\nabla_i\nu,\partial_j\Phi_t\ \right)?$$ And then, the term $g\left(\ (\partial_i\phi)\nu,\partial_j\Phi_t\ \right)$ dies out because $\nu$ is perpendicular to $\partial_j\Phi_t$? Thank you.

Comment: @Wombat, yes. That is correct. One quibble is that in what you wrote in your comment, $\partial_i(\phi\nu)$ should be $\nabla_i(\phi\nu)$.

Comment: @Deane Sir, how did you know $g\left( \nabla_i\nu,(\Phi_t)_*\partial_j \right)=A_{ij}$? If I follow the textbook by John M. Lee, the scalar second fundamental form $A$ is defined by $A(X,Y)=g(sX,Y)$, where $s$ is the shape operator. Now the Weingarten equation tells us $\nabla_i\nu=s\partial_i$. So we get $g\left( \nabla_i\nu,(\Phi_t)_*\partial_j \right)=g\left( s\partial_i,(\Phi_t)_*\partial_j \right)$. This result seems to have nothing to do with $A$. How did you tackle $(\Phi_t)_*\partial_j$? Thank you.